# Função .replace() Python não está funcionando, retorna \n e \r

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython-notebook

```
def read_book(title_path):
       '''
        Read a bokk and return it as string
       '''
       with open(title_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as current_file:
            text = current_file.read()
            text.replace("\n", "").replace("\r","")
       return text

text = read_book(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\PythonWeek3\Books_EngFr\Books_EngFr\English\shakespeare\Romeo and Juliet.txt")

ind = text.find("What's in a name?")
ind

sample_text = text[ind : ind + 1000]
sample_text
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Método `replace` retorna a nova string, então tente fazer `text = text.replace(...)`. Para ais informações, leia a [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) sobre os métodos da string.

Comment: diferentemente das listas, as strings não são editáveis, e por isso o método replace cria uma nova string ao invés de modificar a string original

Comment: o `encoding="utf-8"` funcionou aí? meu txt dá erro quando tento abrir com o jupyter

Comment: @GabrielMendes funcionou sim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings são considerados **objetos imutáveis** em Python, portanto qualquer método de string sempre irá retornar uma nova string. Veja por exemplo:

```
s1 = "Olá Mundo!!!"
s2 = s1.replace("!", "?")
print(s1)
print(s2)

# output:
# Olá Mundo!!!
# Olá Mundo???
```

Portanto, faltou você pegar o valor retornado ao chamar `text.replace`.

Caso você não precise do conteúdo bruto retornado pelo `current_file.read`, dá para fazer a substituição em uma linha da seguinte forma:

```
text = current_file.read().replace("\n", "").replace("\r","")
```